# Python in Pycharm exits with: Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So when i try to run the program (by clicking the buton i created) it freezes and crashes, then the error message appears "Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)" I'm new to programming and I haven't found any explanation for this error. Also note that the program isn't complete yet but i can't continue without this part working properly

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from tkinter import BOTH, END, HORIZONTAL, Tk, scrolledtext, ttk


def osint():
    file = open("list.txt")
    nick = vvod.get()
    label = tk.Label(win, text="Запущен поиск по нику '" + nick + "' ,пожалуйста, ожидайте")
    label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, stick='we')

    for line in file:
        name = line.split(' ')[0]
        site = line.split(' ')[1]

        site = site.rstrip("\n")
        url = site + nick

        try:
            r = requests.get(url)

            if r.status_code == 200:
                console.configure(state='normal')  # enable insert
                y = (("найдено " + name + ": " + url) + '\n')
                console.insert(END, y())
                console.yview(END)  # autoscroll
                console.configure(state='disabled')  # disable editing
            else:
                console.configure(state='normal')  # enable insert
                e = ((name + " не найдено") + '\n')
                console.insert(END, e())
                console.yview(END)  # autoscroll
                console.configure(state='disabled')  # disable editing
        except:
            console.configure(state='normal')  # enable insert
            s = ("ошибка запроса для " + name + '\n')
            console.insert(END, s)
            console.yview(END)  # autoscroll
            console.configure(state='disabled')  # disable editing
    file.close()


win = tk.Tk()
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="icon.png")
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.title("Nickname Finder")
win.geometry("660x550+500+300")
# win.maxsize(1000, 900)
# win.minsize(500, 600)
win.resizable(False, False)
win.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=500)

btn = tk.Button(win, text="Запуск поиска", command=osint)
btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
tx = tk.Label(win, text="Введите никнейм")
tx.grid(row=0, column=0)

vvod = tk.Entry(win)
vvod.grid(row=0, column=1)

console = tkst.ScrolledText(win, state="disabled")
console.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, stick='sn')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I imagine this won't help much, but a bit of Googling suggests that the Windows exit code CFFFFFFF means "application hung"

Comment: thank you all! I solved the problem